# Why conductor is discharged

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity

A person standing on an electrically insulated platform touches a highly charged  electrically isolated conductor; the person doesn't get a shock and conductors get  partially discharged. How does conductor get discharged if there is an insulator-platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excess charge in the conductor flows into the person so that eventually both the person and conductor are at the same electrical potential. The statement, "the person doesn't get a shock" is ambiguous, because there is certainly a brief current flow as the potentials are equalized, and if its high enough the person would feel it and thus we would say the person felt a "shock".

I'm assuming your question, "how conductor get discharged if there is a insulator platform" refers to the popular misconception that there must be a complete circuit for there to be any current flow. That is simply not true--at least for brief flow between objects of different potential. The only reason to make a complete circuit is if you want constant flow from a constant source of such flow, like a battery or generator. Otherwise there would only be a brief flow that equalizes the potential of a charge from a source to a destination.

Answer (score 0):

Human body, though is a poor conductor, does share some charges.  Since the feet are insulated, no (permanent) currents are built up.  That's why we call it **electrostatic**.  That's exactly what happens in Van der Graaff generator experiment.

[image]

Comment: But my qns remain same how electricity pass insulator??

Comment: Dry skin has resistance between $1,000-100,000 \: \Omega$.  Temporary current flows within your body **not to the ground**!!